# Hardware that can spoof mA usage or cause it

Tags: usb, plug, current-drain

I have a device that is expecting to trigger when the TV turns on/off except I can't plug the TV directly into it. I have a WeMo smart plug which is meant to spoof the TV turning on/off however, I need it to pull enough of a significant draw of power to trigger the device.

Basically, I'm looking for something to plug into the WeMo that is designed to be inefficient OR a device that can spoof mA usage when it's on. Not sure if spoofing mA usage is possible without actually spending electricity but I figure I'd ask.

I tried plugging in a usb power bank which was good until it was fully charged. I'd then need to discharge it but wasting energy somewhere else (and it's very inconvenient to remove from where I need to put it). I also tried plugging into an old phone and using an app to cause the phone to require more power but I'm afraid of the phone getting too hot.

I'm thinking maybe there's a small circuit to trick a usb plug to think it's always needing power?

Comment: Can't you just plug in a small light into the smart switch - probably just a nightlight would draw enough power to be detected.

Comment: The device would need to be behind the TV and the light might be distracting.

Comment: this appears to be an XY problem ... why are you doing this? ... what is the end goal?

Comment: End goal is to trigger the device that is normally looking for the TV to turn on/off without actually attaching the power of the TV to the device.

Comment: You could get an AC plug with screw terminals and wire a 100k ohm 1/2 watt resistor between the terminals. In US 117 V system, it will draw about 1 mA, and generate 0.1 watts of heat, well within dissipation limits of resistor. But not UL approved! I’d use a nightlight and paint it black.

Comment: @donnie that doesn't sound like an end goal. What is the reason you want to trigger that device? This sounds like an automation problem that you try to solve by doing a strange thing, where the right thing might be much easier.

Comment: It sure sounds like it would be easier to find a way to plug the TV into the plug. But I guess that is so obvious that you would have done already done it. Must not be an option for some reason. You could probably plug almost anything into the WeMo. A night light, a small fan, something like that.

Comment: @mmmm, yes the right thing would be easier but due to the location of these components I cannot do it. Hence the question.

Answer (score 2):

It depends how 'smart' the device is that's detecting the TV power draw.

It may be detecting the current magnitude. In this case you can connect a series combo of an X-class capacitor, and a small resistor to protect things from excess current surge at connection. If most of the voltage drop is across the capacitor, then very little power will be dissipated. Most (all?) consumer electricity meters are smart enough to charge you for only the small power loss in the resistor, not the large VAr provided by the capacitor.

It may be detecting the power drawn. This is unlikely in a cheap go/no-go device, as it means detecting the time average of volts*current like your electricity meter does, but it's still possible. If that's the case, then you've got to draw the power.

Comment: The device claims to be monitoring thresholds of mA, which is why I mentioned it in the post. I don't know much about electrical engineering to know if that could mean two things.

Comment: @DonnieD'Amato True power is unlikely in a cheap device, chances are it's just looking at the mA, inwhich case a capacitor, protected by a resistor, would give you a near wattless load.

Comment: Is there any prefab solution? I don't have the equipment to build something but I certainly have the tools to take something apart.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to draw a few watts of power you could try using an approved AC adapter with (say) 12V 1A output (use whatever you have around) and add a resistor to give the desired power dissipation.

\$R= V^2/P\$.

That is electrically safe, but if the resistor is dissipating a lot of heat it could get too hot. Putting it inside a metal case or screwed to an aluminum plate would solve that.

This style of resistor is convenient and not too expensive (photo from Digikey):

[image]